# Multitenancy in ASP.NET Core 2.0+

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, multi-tenant, saaskit

**Bakground:**
I want to develop a multi-tenant application in ASP.NET Core and have been looking into Ben Fosters [Saaskit](https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit) library which seems to provide good solutions for common problems in multitenancy applications.

**Problem:**
The SaasKit have a `UsePerTenant` method which is nice for doing different things per-request depending on current tenant.

My goal is to use the `UsePerTenant` method combined with different `IOptions` objects injected via dependency injection. This can be used in the authentication middleware like

```
AddAuthentication().AddCookie(..).AddOpenIdConnect(...)
```

Which is configured in the `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    // Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
    }

    // Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I can’t make the authentication middleware in ASP.NET 2.0+ use different `IOptions` objects per-request since the `ConfigureServices` method in the Startup.cs file only runs once every application startup and the `UsePerTenant` method should be used in the `Configure` method which is running for each incoming/outgoing request in the ASP.NET pipeline.

**Question:**
How to dynamically change cookie and OpenID Connect options in the `ConfigureServices` method based on current tenant?

Comment: Possible solution currently as a pull request in the SaasKit library https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit/pull/96

Comment: 1. Create a Service IUserAuthenticationManager, 2. Make it a singleton which has an IHTTPAccessor in it, 3. Create a property which accessing it will resolve your userid from the HTTPCurrent Context. 4.  Use that userId to create you access rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following PR provides a solution for the above question.
https://github.com/saaskit/saaskit/pull/96

<s>The PR have been merged with the "master" branch now.</s>

It wasn't merged yet (November 2018)

Comment: I can't see any commit on master branch after Jul 18, 2016.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a good way to get per tenant options for any type of ASP.NET Core options, including cookie or openID Connect. I have wrapped this up into a framework called Finbuckle.MultiTenant.

It basically boils down to a setup that looks like this:

```
services.AddMultiTenant().
            WithInMemoryStore()).
            WithRouteStrategy().
            WithPerTenantOptionsConfig<CookieAuthenticationOptions>((o, tenantContext) => o.Cookie.Name += tenantContext.Id);
```

See my here for more information if you are curious: https://www.finbuckle.com/MultiTenant

Comment: Can this solution use with IdentityServer4?

Comment: @Sampath,

For authentication options yes because IS4 uses the normal options under the hood. For data it's more complicated -- if you use the ASP.NET Identity plug-in for IdentityServer4 then yes for the user data. The config and operational data would be harder--it would be a lot of work to change the EF plugins for those, but it could be done.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using ASP.net identity + EF Core. And for the API, I'm using .Net Core Web API2. I think we can mange identity server multi-tenant part. Issue is configure API for OIDC. My system is having single DB per client and each client having their own domain.

Comment: @Sampath Per tenant OpenID Connect options are supported. Check out the project webpage at https://www.finbuckle.com/multitenant to see the documentation. If you have any questions just create an issue in the github. -Drew